# gcc-arm linking error: attempted static link of dynamic object

Tags: c, gcc, linker, qemu

I am trying to compile a program with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc containing neon instructions and executing it over Qemu. The code is,

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
void NeonTest(short int * __restrict a, short int * __restrict b, short int * __restrict z)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
z[i] = a[i] * b[i];
        }
}
```

I successfully do it without using `-static` flag. But Qemu does not execute/recognize an executable if `-static` flag is not used. So when I use `-static` to compile and link, I get the following error,

```
junaid@junaid755:~/code/c$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ffast-math -mvectorize-with-neon-quad -S neon_test.c 
junaid@junaid755:~/code/c$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ffast-math -mvectorize-with-neon-quad -c neon_test.s -o neon_test.o 
junaid@junaid755:~/code/c$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -ftree-vectorize -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ffast-math -mvectorize-with-neon-quad neon_test.o -o neon_test 
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/lib/ld-linux.so.3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried the ermine, statifier and other softwares for portable linux applications. But the issue is they work on executables, while in my case the executable generation is causing error.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/145053-attempted-static-link-dynamic-object.html) works for you as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved when i installed `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` on my system. Maybe additional packages installed may have resloved the problem. Now I use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` command instead of `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. Now the exe file is statically linked. But the problem is not totally solved. On qemu it give segmentation fault now.

Comment: Good that you found a solution. About the segfault, you might try [mudflap](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging).